# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid integer:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to JSReact, trying to make an e-commerce store fully functional with Stripe.

I'm getting this error in function emulation

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid integer: $({getBasketTotal(basket) * 100})

and I think the problem is here at the create?total...:

[Code down below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3PcC.png)

```html
useEffect(()   =>{

        const getClientSecret = async () => {
                const response = await axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: 'payments/create?total=$({getBasketTotal(basket) * 100})'
                });
                setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
        }

            getClientSecret();
    }, [basket])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use backticks instead of single quotes if you want to do string interpolation:

```
url: `payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in your template literal

`url: 'payments/create?total=$({getBasketTotal(basket) * 100})'`  - print text as it is.

`url: 'payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}'` - prints the value